# building on linux issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to build SystemUI using Ubuntu, but when I try to download the repo, o just get source files like manifests, not any actual part. So I have the git source of just SystemUI, but I do not know how to build it. I am having troubles installing the parts needed to build (using online tutorials for how to build). If anyone has advice for how to build just that one app in windows preferably, but Linux is fine, it'd be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to download the whole thing as there is such a web of dependencies it is unlikely you could get `SystemUI` to build on its own.

Once you have it installed and build everything, if you are just editing files under the `SystemUI` directory, running `make` in that directory (or using `mm` if you run `. build/envsetup.sh`) will build just that project, but then again you have the problem of inserting a single executable into the system image...

Comment: Ah thanks! So I have to download the whole master branch? Do I use  -b master in repo to do so?